# HTTP 401 Error while trying to read data from Vimeo's oEmbed endpoint

Tags: python, urllib2, vimeo, oembed

To embed videos provided from Vimeo/Youtube/Dailymotion.. I'm "grabbing" data using oEmbed standard. This works fine for Youtube, Dailymotion and Soundcloud but not with Vimeo.
Should I get authenticated to get this data?

Here is how I am managing to get it working.

```
url = "http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?%s" % 
                                      urllib.urlencode({"url": url})
headers = {'User-Agent':  'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'}
req = urllib2.Request(url, "", headers)
obj = simplejson.loads(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
```

And as a error I get **HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized**

Traceback:

```
File "/path/to/module/models.py" in save
  87.             obj = simplejson.loads(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in urlopen
  126.     return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in open
  397.             response = meth(req, response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in http_response
  510.                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in error
  435.             return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in _call_chain
  369.             result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in http_error_default
  518.         raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
```

Any idea anyone?

Comment: Well, it seems that I had to change `urllib2.Request(url, "", headers)` into `urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)`

The Request class expects either a None value (then make a GET request) or data to be sent (then make a POST request). And it seems that vimeo doesn't accepts POST requests on his oEmbed Endpoint.